# WordPress not generating sub menues correctly for custom navbar

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create an additional nav-menu for a site. I followed some guides first but have reverted to copy pasting the themes navbar to debug, but this did not solve my issue.

When I add sub-menues to the WordPress menu these simply appear as menu items bellow the menu, not in a drop down.

See the site at https://myrightdev.funka.website/ 
[image: Screenshots showing sub menu items simply shown bellow menu items]

I can see from chrome dev tools that the main navbar (the one with the logo) gets an  for menu items. but I am un-sure of where in the code this is inserted. See my header.php for my details, the secondary navigation menu is named secondary_navigation

```
<?php
/**
 * Header file for the Twenty Twenty WordPress default theme.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since Twenty Twenty 1.0
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>

    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php
wp_body_open();
?>

<header id="site-header" class="header-footer-group" role="banner">
<?php
            if (has_nav_menu('secondary_navigation') || !has_nav_menu('expanded')) {
                ?>

    <div class="header-navigation-wrapper">
        <nav class="secondary-menu-wrapper"
        >
        <ul class="secondary-menu reset-list-style">

            <?php
            if (has_nav_menu('secondary_navigation')) {
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'container' => '',
                    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
                    'menu_class' => 'secondaryMenuClass',
                    'theme_location' => 'secondary_navigation',

                ));
            } elseif (!has_nav_menu('expanded')) {

                            wp_list_pages(
                                array(
                                    'match_menu_classes' => true,
                                    'show_sub_menu_icons' => true,
                                    'title_li' => false,
                                    'walker' => new TwentyTwenty_Walker_Page(),
                                )
                            );

                        }
            ?>
        </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
    <?php
            }
                ?>


    <div class="header-inner section-inner">

        <div class="header-titles-wrapper">


            <?php

            // Check whether the header search is activated in the customizer.
            $enable_header_search = get_theme_mod('enable_header_search', true);

            if (true === $enable_header_search) {

                ?>

                <button class="toggle search-toggle mobile-search-toggle" data-toggle-target=".search-modal"
                        data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="toggle-inner">
                                <span class="toggle-icon">
                                    <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg('search'); ?>
                                </span>
                                <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e('Search', 'twentytwenty'); ?></span>
                            </span>
                </button><!-- .search-toggle -->

            <?php } ?>

            <div class="header-titles">

                <?php
                // Site title or logo.
                twentytwenty_site_logo();

                // Site description.
                twentytwenty_site_description();
                ?>

            </div><!-- .header-titles -->

            <button class="toggle nav-toggle mobile-nav-toggle" data-toggle-target=".menu-modal"
                    data-toggle-body-class="showing-menu-modal" aria-expanded="false"
                    data-set-focus=".close-nav-toggle">
                        <span class="toggle-inner">
                            <span class="toggle-icon">
                                <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg('ellipsis'); ?>
                            </span>
                            <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e('Menu', 'twentytwenty'); ?></span>
                        </span>
            </button><!-- .nav-toggle -->

        </div><!-- .header-titles-wrapper -->


        <div class="header-navigation-wrapper">


            <?php
            if (has_nav_menu('primary') || !has_nav_menu('expanded')) {
                ?>

                <nav class="primary-menu-wrapper" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e('Horizontal', 'twentytwenty'); ?>"
                     role="navigation">


                    <ul class="primary-menu reset-list-style">

                        <?php

                        if (has_nav_menu('primary')) {

                            wp_nav_menu(
                                array(
                                    'container' => '',
                                    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
                                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                )
                            );
                        } elseif (!has_nav_menu('expanded')) {

                            wp_list_pages(
                                array(
                                    'match_menu_classes' => true,
                                    'show_sub_menu_icons' => true,
                                    'title_li' => false,
                                    'walker' => new TwentyTwenty_Walker_Page(),
                                )
                            );

                        }
                        ?>

                    </ul>

                </nav><!-- .primary-menu-wrapper -->

                <?php
            }

            if (true === $enable_header_search || has_nav_menu('expanded')) {
                ?>

                <div class="header-toggles hide-no-js">

                    <?php
                    if (has_nav_menu('expanded')) {
                        ?>

                        <div class="toggle-wrapper nav-toggle-wrapper has-expanded-menu">

                            <button class="toggle nav-toggle desktop-nav-toggle" data-toggle-target=".menu-modal"
                                    data-toggle-body-class="showing-menu-modal" aria-expanded="false"
                                    data-set-focus=".close-nav-toggle">
                                    <span class="toggle-inner">
                                        <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e('Menu', 'twentytwenty'); ?></span>
                                        <span class="toggle-icon">
                                            <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg('ellipsis'); ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                            </button><!-- .nav-toggle -->

                        </div><!-- .nav-toggle-wrapper -->

                        <?php
                    }

                    if (true === $enable_header_search) {
                        ?>

                        <div class="toggle-wrapper search-toggle-wrapper">

                            <button class="toggle search-toggle desktop-search-toggle"
                                    data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal"
                                    data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="toggle-inner">
                                        <?php twentytwenty_the_theme_svg('search'); ?>
                                        <span class="toggle-text"><?php _e('Search', 'twentytwenty'); ?></span>
                                    </span>
                            </button><!-- .search-toggle -->

                        </div>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </div><!-- .header-toggles -->
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </div><!-- .header-navigation-wrapper -->

    </div><!-- .header-inner -->

    <?php
    // Output the search modal (if it is activated in the customizer).
    if (true === $enable_header_search) {
        get_template_part('template-parts/modal-search');
    }
    ?>

</header><!-- #site-header -->

<?php
// Output the menu modal.
get_template_part('template-parts/modal-menu');
```

I've tried my best to replicate the menu functionality of the standard twenty twenty theme menu that is bellow the secondary navigation menu. Any ideas on how I can make these sub-menu items behave like the sub-menu items on the twenty twenty menu?

Comment: This appears to be more of a styling issue? Both the menus your screenshot shows, _have_ the sub menu items wrapped in `<ul class="sub-menu">` - that is default functionality you get from using `wp_nav_menu` with a default nav menu walker already. But any kind of _styling_ that would make these sub-menus initially hidden, and only show them when the parent item is hovered, seems to be completely absent.

Comment: Thank you, but even when  I use the exact same CSS classes that are being used in the main menu I still get the same error. Not sure what is happening

Comment: _“Not sure what is happening”_ - and neither can we be, with what you just said. You need to explain or show what _exactly_ you did.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe said, this is a styling issue. If you're trying to get a drop-down that appears on hover, you need to modify the CSS.

```
.secondary-menu > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.secondary-menu li:hover > .sub-menu,
.secondary-menu li:focus > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```